# Dates in the current month after today

Tags: crystal-reports

My report needs to make criteria which pulls data for the current month *and* after today's date.

The following formula works for the current month, so how can I add behavior to show dates after today?

```
{Command.plnshpdat} >= Dateserial(year(currentDate),Month(currentdate),1) and 
{Command.plnshpdat}< dateserial(year(currentdate),Month(Currentdate)+1,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for any dates between today and the first of next month:

```
{Command.plnshpdat} > Date(CurrentDate)
AND
{Command.plnshpdat} < DateSerial(Year(Currentdate), Month(CurrentDate) + 1, 1)
```

Note that we technically don't need to check if the date is after or equal to the first of this month. That logic is redundant now that you're only accepting values after today.

Comment: @Abbas Great, be sure to let me know how it goes.